# How can it be proven that a certain number of integers has a certain number of digits?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across a question in the "Sequences and Series" section of my IB HL Maths textbook. I'm sorry if I'm over-complicating it and wasting anybody's time! 
The question talks about a book in which all pages are numbered starting from one. It then asks to prove that the first 11 pages contain 13 digits. I'm assuming it has to be done by forming an equation for the number of digits in the form of a sum of a series or an arithmetic sequence. I might just be over-complicating it, though, as at this level maths doesn't seem too complicated. I'm really trying to understand this as this is an example of the "harder" questions that could potentially come up on tests and make or break a grade. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how this can be proven, we can prove it by actually counting the number of digits, and get $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,0,1,1$ which is exactly $13$ digits.

Overall, the number of digits in the first $n$ pages depends on the number of digits in $n$.

If the number of digits in $n$ is $k$, then the number of digits in the first $n$ pages is $$9 + 90 + 900 + \cdots + 9\cdot 10^{k-2} + k\cdot (n-10^{k-1}+1)$$

This is because you have to sum

- all the digits in the numbers between $1$ and $10^{k-1}$. There are $9$ single digit numbers, and $90$ two-digit numbers, and $900$ three-digit numbers and so on. You count the number of digits in all numbers *shorter* than $n$ to get $$9+90+\cdots + 9\cdot 10^{k-2}$$
- all the digits in the numbers between $10^{k-1}$ (inclusive) and $n$. There are $n-10^{k-2} + 1$ such numbers, and each has $k$ digits, so the number of digits in this part is $$k\cdot (n-10^{k-1} + 1)$$